# Send additional data with blob through websockets

Tags: javascript, websocket, fileapi

[Websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/send) support sending of blobs, but how do we send additional text data with them?

My use-case is a file uploader. I am slicing each file in multiple parts, and send max 3 parts at once to the server. On the server, I need a way to identify the order of these slices, so I can reconstruct the file. This is why I need to send the index of the slice along with blob, and the name of the file (multiple files can be uploaded)

Comment: I would send the filename first with some unique ID of a fixed length attached to it. Then in each slice of the file, prefix the binary contents with that unique ID and index. On the server side, you can strip from the beginning, the fixed number of bytes that make up this "header" and parse them appropriately.

Comment: maybe got 2 options, either construct a "packet", with index and data, or hash each part, send up the list to create a "transaction" then serverside rehash check each part as it comes in, place in stack once list is complete construct the file.

Comment: Hashing sounds like a good option because that way I verify the integrity of the file as well, but I'm worried it's too heavy on the cpu for the client (browser)

Comment: As far as i understand the websocket protocol already does that by itself its called framing and works exactly as described in the comments and answers here ([Here is a description](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/high-performance-browser/9781449344757/ch17.html#_websocket_protocol)). Just send the whole blob and wait on the server for the onMessage event. It would be intresting if one can access this frames somehow and use them to show progress or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to send metadata with binary data is delimiting by size. You can generate a random number to identify a file (a 64 bit int or a UUID). Prepend this number to all file chunks, then prepend the chunk number (say 2 bytes). So you'll have a protocol that looks like this: first 8 bytes (or 16 if you choose UUID) are for the identifier then 2 bytes for the chunk number then the data. Send the metadata first as a normal JSON. Metadata will have the filename and the ID and may be other data you may want like the number of chunks. Of cause there can be much more ways to solve this.

Comment: hello, is it possible for you to share a code snippet. I as trying it but not able to achieve. thanks